# Set PostgreSQL configuration parameter in SQLAlchemy

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I'm using *Pyramid* and *SQLAlchemy* for my REST server. For the logging purposes I need some way how to determine user name in postgresql after update trigger function. One way is setting some runtime configuration parameter before update execution and using this value in trigger function.

In *psql* terminal it can be done using

```
set myapp.user_name = 'User Name';
```

This parameter will be subsequently used in postgresql trigger.

Is it possible to set this parameter in *Pyramid* / *SQLAlchemy* application? 
I suppose I can use *SQLAlchemy* Events. But I'm not sure which event is correct for this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register a Pyramid event handler which would set the parameter on any new request:

```
from pyramid import events

def on_new_request(event):
    """
    you can access request as event.request 
    and the current registry settings as event.request.registry.settings
    """
    session = DBSession()
    session.execute("SET blah TO 'foo'")


def app(global_config, **settings):

    config = Configurator(...)
    config.add_subscriber(on_new_request, events.NewRequest)
```

See [Deployment Settings](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/startup.html#deployment-settings) and [events.NewRequest](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/events.html?highlight=events#pyramid.events.NewRequest) for more details.

One thing to watch out is to make sure you're always using the same session object - SQLAlchemy maintains a pool of connections and, if you commit your session, all subsequent operations will use a brand-new session which is not pre-configured with your settings. In other words, you should not do session.commit(), session.rollback(), transaction.commit() etc. in your code and instead rely on ZopeTransactionExtension committing/rolling back the transaction at the end of the request/response cycle. Which is a recommended practice anyway.

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Thanks. I'm using ZopeTransactionExtension. No commit(), in some cases only I call session.flush().

Comment: Yes, Sergey is correct this pattern will work well.  I prefer to use the subscriber syntax personally: `@subscriber(NewResponse)` http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/hooks.html#subscriber-predicates

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the exact command you're running with `set myapp.user = "User Name"`.

When you say "In psql this can be done using..." I'm assuming you are running some sort of SQL command, although the command you listed is not a valid command, at least not typically.

In any event, arbitrary SQL can be executed in SQLAlchemy using the `.execute()` method.

```
session = Session()
session.execute("select 1;")
```

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/session.html?highlight=execute#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.execute

Comment: And you run that from the PSQL prompt?  `=> set myapp.user_name = 'User Name';` ?  Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes. I need some way how to determine user name in postgresql trigger function. One way is setting some configuration parameter before update statement and using this value in after update trigger function.

Comment: If you just need to execute that command my answer will do that, I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to do... Can you clarify if it's something more than running that one command?

Comment: Yes, I just need execute that command. I'm finding the right place to do it in my Pyramid application. Maybe it can be done in pyramid login view method after successfully login.

Comment: do you need it once per user session or on every request?  Every request I'd recommend adding a tween to automatically handle it for you

Comment: It is REST server, so I think I need to call this command once per request.